# Are there any other anonymous developers like Satoshi Nakamoto and BCNext that abandoned their project?

Tags: privacy, satoshi-nakamoto

I'm doing some research on anonymous developers in the crypto currency space. Satoshi Nakamoto was the first to create a crypto currency and then vanish from existence. Another one was BCNext that create the NXT platform and then vanished.

What other anonymous developers took the same approach?

Answer (score 3):

There is also the CryptoNote creator Nicolas van Saberhagen.

From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptoNote#Controversy_and_criticism:

> The author of the white paper went by the name Nicolas van Saberhagen,
>   although like Satoshi Nakamoto (the author of the bitcoin white paper)
>   that name is likely a pseudonym. Saberhagen's true identity and
>   location remains unknown. Some have claimed that the real creator is
>   someone in the bitcoin community.

It gets interesting, because the community found the first CryptoNote (Bytecoin BCN) currency to be a likely scam.
The controversy is regarding the creator himself likely pre-mining the coin in secret before the "official" launch, as well as suspected of having an unfair mining advantage because of publishing a handicapped miner (later fixed by the community).
To give weight to the controversy, seems like the timestamps of the original whitepaper were fabricated as well.

For a longer read, the details have been presented here: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=740112.0

> tl;dr - CryptoNote developers faked dates in whitepapers. Bytecoin
>   faked dates in fake blockchain to facilitate an 82% premine, and
>   CryptoNote backed them up.

Comment: Could you please elaborate in this post what is strange about his story? Is he anonymous as requested by the asker? Sending us off to read a wall of text on another platform before even answering the main inquiry of the asker classifies as a "link-only" answer, which is a reason for an answer to be removed on this platform. Answers are expected to provide sufficient detail to stand on their own. Also see: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/232061)

Comment: Yes, he's anonymous, and also attempted to get rich by pre-mining the first coin based on the protocol. Sorry, will update, give me a minute

Comment: alright, edited, how is it now?